I have a Greek seasonal residence permit. Can I go back to my country from Poland instead of Greece without any issue?
Can I make an exit from different country, if my residence permit is from Greece?

In principle yes, you can exit through a different country in the Schengen area, it happens all the time. If you are not on a layover (i.e. you don't have a flight ticket from Greece to a non-Schengen country), border guards may ask you what you were doing in Poland. If you have a credible answer, they will probably leave it at that, if they ask at all. Depending on your citizenship and the specifics of your stay, they may however ask you for more details or evidence.
What would create problems is working in Poland or staying there longer than you should have (90 days) without actually residing in Greece, not the mere fact that you are exiting through another country.
